# comparison of flot versus google charts

Tags: flot, google-visualization

I am starting up a website that needs a lot of sophisticated multi line charts.  I see two top candidates for the job

1. [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)
2. [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/linechart.html)

Does anyone have any recommendations or preferences on this decision?

Comment: I think Flot's prettier, but that's just me.

Comment: it will be interesting to have an answer in favor of Google charts, as so far I see flot is a preferred library in all the answers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Google charts: You will need to call out to google every time you need to plot.
  Is it acceptable to do this from your website?
- Control: Flot is the clear winner in this category, as you have a very high degree of  control over plots.  Also, Flot is pretty fast! I have used it personally, and once you get the hang of the API, it is great.  Further, there are many 'plugins' that can be written (and some are available) for flot.  I think this is a great feature.

Overall, I would vote for Flot.

- Edit:  Also look at http://www.highcharts.com/, a great charting library (if you can figure out the licensing).

Comment: the licensing is a nightmare, thats the reason i used flot over highcharts

Comment: Flot doesn't have a native smoothing option.  You have to run the graph through a separate Smooth() script.  Google has a simple option to smooth graph.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305628/flot-curved-lines-spline-plugin-which-works-with-fillbetween-plugin

Comment: I am to be honest, surprised that Flot gets the vote in the comments and in the accepted answer.  Are there no proponents for Google Charts, or is Flot just that clearly superior?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of nice plugins for features like radar graphs (spider graphs), Gantt charts, cluster graphs, 3D effects, gradients effects and lots more in Flot.
Flot is also open source and under the MIT license, which gives you complete freedom in using it (even commercially) without having to apply a similar license.

Answer (score 0):

What if Google discontinues their chart service? In case you were wondering, they are well within their rights to do so, and in a few months' notice at that: https://developers.google.com/chart/terms.

Plus, client-side charts will naturally be far better for *dynamic* charts, which is essentially the standard these days.